# How can I upgrade from Ubuntu 6.06?

Tags: upgrade

Please help me upgrade my Ubuntu cause it's hard for me to update firefox and can't install Flash player. I tried the terminal but it didn't work.

Answer (score 7):

You have a really old version of Ubuntu installed, which is already End of Life (EOL). Have a look here for upgrade to the current version. Need to be done in multiple upgrades.

- [Dapper to Hardy upgrade](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades/Dapper)
- Next would be [Hardy to Lucid](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades/Hardy)
- and the last one [Lucid to Precise](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PreciseUpgrades)

**Don't forget to do a backup before upgrading, if you have any data on your machine**

Answer (score 3):

I would seriously consider backing up your data and doing a clean install in your situation.

- [Download the Latest version](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop)
- [Release Notes](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PrecisePangolin/ReleaseNotes/UbuntuDesktop)
- [Read how to do an install](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GraphicalInstall)

Comment: amen, it's better off to do a clean install than upgrade from an ancient version

Comment: absolutely : as an aside while creating links like that looks pretty - I, for one, much prefer to see what a link is before hovering to check ;)

Comment: you're free to rollback changes; I won't edit such links from you then. To me makes more sense to know what a link is about & hover to find the actual link. But, personal tastes differ.

Comment: I'm not THAT worried :)

Answer (score -3):

Try this in your terminal (ctrl+alt+t):

`sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`

If it does not help, what's displayed in a terminal?

Answer (score -4):

Type the following in the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

It should automatically upgrade your Ubuntu installation.

Comment: upgrade doesn't do dist-upgrades.

Comment: This does not actually resolve the issue at hand as it won't upgrade between overall versions.